# how do I add html to a Jenkins log with the Jenkins-dsl?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I can inject text using `echo 'foobar'`, but if I add `echo <h1>foobar</h1>` it outputs the html as a text and not parsed markup.

Comment: what information do you want to add to html? Will it be big?

Comment: I would be happy with just inline tags for now

Comment: In console output? In build description?

Comment: Console output,  thanks

Comment: I'm not sure if it's possible to do this, but for highlight output you can try [AnsiColor Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/AnsiColor+Plugin) and  [Log Parser Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Log+Parser+Plugin).